# string print table format dynamically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am new in Receipt concept in swift. I want to print receipt like below image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB4bV.jpg

My Code:

```
let result = formattedString(left: "MAXIS Hotlink", right: "25.00",left1: "1") 
    + "\n" + formattedString(left:"DIGI Prepaid", right: "5.00",left1: "0") 
    + "\n" + formattedString(left:"CELCOM Xpax", right: "5.00",left1: "2")

print(result)


func formattedString(left: String, right: String,left1: String, width: Int = 20) -> String {
      // The `max` call returns 0 if `width - left.count` is negative
      let filler = String(repeating: " ", count: max(0, width - left.count))
      return left + filler + right + filler + left1
}
```

But receipt not properly aligned when length increased. I want to print the string like below imagetype. Please anybody help me

Comment: Aligning a string with space characters is the worst choice. There are tabs or multiple labels/text fields.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the receipt in the image, formatted string is not a good solution. Instead, you should have a template jpg. Then, you should draw information over the template. In this case, you can use a blank jpg file with a relevant size to have a receipt.

For example;

```
func getReceipt() -> UIImage? {
    
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "receipt.jpg") else {return nil}

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let toFromFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16.0)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
            
    let subjectMessageAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16.0)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
    
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let itemRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), size: image.size)
    let itemText = "item"
    itemText.draw(in: itemRect, withAttributes: toFromFontAttributes)
    
    let quantityRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 50), size: image.size)
    let quantityText = "Quantity"
    quantityText.draw(in: quantityRect, withAttributes: toFromFontAttributes)

    ......
    // add other items
    ......

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage ?? nil
}
```

Comment: you should have a template image to draw/write receipt over it. You can create a blank white jpg file in your computer, then rename it to something like "receipt.jpg" or whatever you want. Finally, you should copy that file to your project.